# Xamarin.Forms get ViewModel as BindingContext in ViewCell of ListView

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, binding-context

I add `DataTemplateSelector` in FlowListView(Basically same as `ListView`).

```xml
<ContentView
    ...
    BindingContext="{Binding PatientImageListVM, Source={StaticResource VMLocator}}">
    ...
    <flv:FlowListView
        ...
        HasUnevenRows="true">
        <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
            <local:PatientImageListDataTemplateSelector/>
        </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
    </flv:FlowListView>
</ContentView>
```

And I use this code for get cell with binding.

```cs
button.SetBinding(Button.CommandParameterProperty, ".");
```

But I want to use some variables in `ViewModel` binded with `ContentView` in `DataTemplateSelector`. I tried this code but not working.

```cs
label.SetBinding(Label.IsVisibleProperty, 
    "{Binding BindingContext.LabelVisibility, Source={x:Reference Page}}");
```

How can I get a vatiable in `ViewModel` in `DataTemplateSellector`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
label.SetBinding(Label.IsVisibleProperty, new Binding("BindingContext.LabelVisibility", source: this));
```

This should works. You should pass the "Page" to your binding with "this". So you should set your binding when you create the ItemTemplate

```
lv.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
{
    //....
    label.SetBinding(Label.IsVisibleProperty, new Binding("BindingContext.LabelVisibility", source: this));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwser.
I found solution `"{Binding ImageListVM.LabelVisibility, Source={StaticResource VMLocator}}"`.
When I replace with your code, it works, too.